# Docker MySQL connection DBeaver

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dbeaver, dbconnection

I just finished following this Docker tutorial on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXY0MLHP3hA&lc=Ugzp3vKtSOp0rn2lYyd4AaABAg

I was able to create a couple of Docker containers for PHP and MySQL.  The file structure is as follows:

```
>Docker_PHP_MySQL
 >DB
   -Dockerfile
 >src
   -index.php
 >www
   -Dockerfile
 development.env
 docker-compose.yml
```

The DB Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:8.0
```

index.php:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('tut07-db', getenv('MYSQL_USER'), getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'), 'information_schema');
if($mysqli->connect_error) 
{
  echo 'Connection Error [', $mysqli->connect_errno, ']: ', $mysqli->connect_error;
} 
else 
{
  echo 'MySQLi Connected Successfully!';
}
?>
```

The www Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

Here is the development.env file:

```
MYSQL_USER=sys_admin
MYSQL_PASSWORD=sys_password
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
```

And then finally, the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

networks:
  tut07-frontend:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.10.1.0/24
  tut07-backend:
    driver: bridge
    ipam: 
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.10.2.0/23

services:
  tut07-db:
    build: ./db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      tut07-backend:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.3.2
    env_file:
      - ./development.env
  tut07-www:
    build: ./www
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
    networks:
      tut07-backend:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.2.2
      tut07-frontend:
        ipv4_address: 172.10.1.2
    depends_on:
      - tut07-db
    env_file:
      - ./development.env
```

Now here's where I know I'm going in completely blind...

In dbeaver, I'm trying to establish a connection:

[image]

But when I test the connection, I get the following response:

[image]

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of giving `localhost_compliant-db` as the Server Host in dbeaver, try giving it `localhost`.

`3306` port is bind on the host machine as well hence `localhost:3306` from your host machine should work.

PS - I presume dbeaver and docker compose stack both are on the same machine. If not, you need to map `localhost_compliant-db` to certain IP which your host machine can understand.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I will test and let you know.

Comment: I updated the server to localhost, but now I am receiving a new connection error, which reads as follows: Access denied for user 'root'@'172.10.2.1' (using password: YES)

Comment: That's an altogether different issue i.e w.r.t permissions in DB. Raise a new question if possible. This issue was mainly related to establishing connection to the DB container which seems to be resolved now.

Comment: I was thinking I should ask another question.  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 22):

For those who are running DB on different machine, you can do the following:

First, from where the container is, run `docker ps` to get the containers details including the `Container ID`

```
[root@test-001 ~]# docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
1b02333fb3b9        tutum/nginx              "/usr/sbin/nginx"        6 weeks ago         Up 7 days           0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       docker_nginx_1
8c1d234a3731        mariadb                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 weeks ago         Up 7 days           0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   docker_mysql_1
```

After you get the ID of your database container, run `docker inspect CONTAINER_ID` to get the related IP address of that container.

```
[root@test-001 ~]# docker inspect 8c1d234a3731 | grep -i IPAddress
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "172.23.0.3",
```

On Dbeaver, after selecting the DB type on adding new connection window, Go to `network settings (SSH, ...)` then put your docker machine details. and from the main page, in the `Server Host:` add the IP you got from the `docker inspect` command, then your credentials.

This should work

Comment: Hi!. what shall I enter for server-host in main page. I entered 127.0.0.1 or localhost, even tried the path to mysql but did not work

Comment: It should be your server IP, if you are running this on your local machine, then 127.0.0.1 should work.

Answer (score 9):

**A very clean way**

1- `docker compose up -d`

2- `docker ps`

3- `docker inspect <database container id> | grep -i IPAddress`

4- Enter the IP value in the server-host field in DBeaver

Comment: Easy, to the point. Brilliant :)

Answer (score 6):

If it is possible change the permission in driver properties `allowPublicKeyRetrieval` to `true`. This is working for me.

`AllowPublicKeyRetrieval=True`

Comment: In my case I was getting a `Public Key Retrieval is not allowed` and this just solved the issue perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was using DBBeaver to connect to MariaDB on port 3306 however my container port was not mapped to my local 3306 port so I just needed to add the ports config into the docker-compose.yml

```
ports:
- "3306:3306"
```

Answer (score 3):

Im my case, as I have different mysql containers and I need to set a different port mapping for each mysql container.

For example,
I use the port setting below for one of mysql containers in the docker-compose.yml.

```
ports:
- "5500:3306"
```

So, I need to set the `host: localhost`, `port: 5500` in DBeaver to connect the mysql container.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine when I fill the port mapping (-p) when initializing the container.
ie:

> docker run **-p 3306:3306** -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes -v c:\Volumes\mysql:/var/lib/mysql  mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try using ***host.docker.internal*** instead

It's working for me