# How to connect to mysql database running inside docker from dbreaver remotely through ssh?

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu, ssh, dbeaver

I am trying to connect to mysql database running in docker inside remote ubuntu VM.
I have dbeaver installed locally in my windows 11 and trying to access the mysql database by ssh.

This is what I have tried and failed:
[Docker MySQL connection DBeaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55931321/docker-mysql-connection-dbeaver)